# Matrices that can only be permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are two $n×n$ matrices with non negative integer entries such that $AB=I$ then $A$ and $B$ are permutation matrices?

Permutation matrices are matrices with the columns just a permutation of the identity matrix.

How do I proceed. Can somebody give hint?

Comment: See several proofs [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62125/invertible-matrices-of-natural-numbers-are-permutations-why).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : Which pairs of vectors with non-negative integers have scalar-product $0$ or $1$ ?

Comment: Additional hint : Use $A^TB^T=(BA)^T=I^T=I$ and the row-sum-norm

Comment: i can see that if any of the entries in $A$ is greater than $1$ then since the product with entries from B has to result in a $0$ or $1$ then that column of B has to be zero which contradicts the invertibility of B

Comment: Excellent. Now rule out that we have more than one $1$ in any column or row. Finally rule out a zero-row/zero-column (almost trivial)